# Using a callback function...Jquery .Get

Tags: jquery

I've been searching and searching for an easy to understand answer, but i can't find one.

I have a jquery .get ajax function to run something, it takes about 10 seconds to run because i have a wait in the php doc. I want to run it again after the 10 seconds pass, so basically when the ajax function finishes. Im thinking of using a callback, but i have no idea how to structure it or should i use a while loop or .. im lost...

heres my code that i have so far

```
function listen(callbackFn) {
    $.get('thread.php?tag=<? echo $tag ?>&username=<? if($_SESSION['loggedin']=='true'){echo $_SESSION['username '];} ?>', function(data) {
        $('#chats').append(data);
        callbackFn;
    });
};
```

Comment: You want to make the same call to .get() again after the original call?  Is this something that repeats every ten seconds throughout the life of the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
(function repeat_request(){
    $.get('thread.php?tag=<? echo $tag ?>&username=<? if($_SESSION['loggedin']=='true'){echo $_SESSION['username'];} ?>', 
        function(data) { 
            $('#chats').append(data); 
            repeat_request();
        }
    );
})();
```

The function called `repeat_request` is executed as soon as the previous request succeeds. Note that if any request fails (say the user's internet momentarily disconnects) the request will stop repeating. If you want it to keep repeating you should use `.complete()` instead of success like this:

```
(function repeat_request(){
    $.get('thread.php?tag=<? echo $tag ?>&username=<? if($_SESSION['loggedin']=='true'){echo $_SESSION['username'];} ?>', 
        function(data) { 
            $('#chats').append(data); 
        }
    ).complete(repeat_request);
})();
```

Comment: i can't seem to get it working, im using firebug and it seems to just run one time, and then it doesn't call the recursive function anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in a function and call it recursively with a timeout of 10 seconds:

```
function do() {
    $.get('...', function (data) {
        // data processing...

        setTimeout(do, 10000);
    });
}

do();
```

Comment: Assuming this is what is wanted, I like it better to have the client browser use setInterval than having the php wait 10 seconds.

Comment: well...i have to make the php wait 10 seconds..im doing long polling. But, in this case, i can still put the function in the success block right?

Comment: @scott It seems the PHP processing takes a while (which may be due to a wait, due to latency or any number of other factors) and the next call should be initiated 10 seconds after the previous one finishes. That's what this does. And it makes sense IMO. Having an interval may quickly lead to constant requests to the server with no pause in between.

Comment: @Robert Just making PHP wait is not long-polling. What is PHP waiting for?

Comment: its not technically waiting, its continually doing sql queries with little waits inbetween for a total of 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to wrap that into a function and call it recursively:

```
function poll() {
    $.get('thread.php?tag=<? echo $tag ?>&username=<? if($_SESSION['loggedin']=='true'){echo $_SESSION['username'];} ?>', function(data) { 

            $('#chats').append(data); 
            poll();
    });
}

poll();
```

This will pretty much poll forever every time the Ajax call returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
function listen()
{
$.get('thread.php?tag=<?php echo $tag ?>&username=<?php
if($_SESSION['loggedin']=='true'){echo $_SESSION['username'];} ?>', 
    function(data) { 
        $('#chats').append(data); 
        setTimeout(listen,100); // prevent recursive call
    } 
);  
};
```